# How to refresh data of recyclerview in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I post API in `HomePageActivity` and get the `Data`, and I use the parameters to pass the data to `NewFragment` and show it.

Now, what I want is that when the user in `NewFragment` uses the `swiperefresh`, NewFragment will call the function in HomePageActivty, and the function will clean the data and recall the post API to get the new data and write into the parameters to send to `NewFragment`, then NewFragment will reload the new data and show it.

I can call the function in `HomePageActivty` and recall the post API, but when I want to reload the data to `NewFragment`, it can't show it!

How can I fix this issue?

Here is my `HomePageActivity`:

```
public class HomePageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String TAG = "HomePageActivity";

    private postSectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public static String[] HomeToNew_user_icon, HomeToNew_user_name, HomeToNew_post_time, HomeToNew_post_text, HomeToNew_post_img, HomeToNew_post_likes, HomeToNew_post_comments, HomeToNew_post_pid = null;
    public static int NewArrayLength;

    private static String token;

    public static Context context;

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        context = HomePageActivity.this;

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new postSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        token = MainActivity.memoryToken;
        Toast.makeText(this,"Token in HomePage: " + token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new JSONTask_New(HomePageActivity.this, token, "0", block).execute("api");

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(R.string.New_Tab);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(R.string.Hot_Tab);

    }

    public static void refresh_New_Data(){
        initData();
        reLoad();
    }

    public static void initData(){
        HomeToNew_user_icon = null;
        HomeToNew_user_name = null;
        HomeToNew_post_time = null;
        HomeToNew_post_text = null;
        HomeToNew_post_img = null;
        HomeToNew_post_likes = null;
        HomeToNew_post_comments = null;
        HomeToNew_post_pid = null;
        NewArrayLength = 0;
    }

    public static void reLoad(){
        new JSONTask_New(context, token, "0", "1").execute("http://52.69.75.199/cp/posts/");
        Log.e(TAG, "REFRESH New(HomePage) ApiCall posts!");
    }

    public class postSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public postSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new NewFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new HotFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Post New (GET).
    public static class JSONTask_New extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private Context context;
        private String token;
        private String type;
        private String block;

        public JSONTask_New(Context context, String token, String type, String block) {
            this.context = context;
            this.token = token;
            this.type = type;
            this.block = block;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                String SERVER_WS_URL = params[0];

                LinkedHashMap<String, String> parameter = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                parameter.put("token", token);
                parameter.put("type",  "0");
                parameter.put("block",  "0");

                return ApiCall.getWebserviceCall(SERVER_WS_URL, parameter); 

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {

                if (result != null) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());

                    String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                    String desc = jsonObject.getString("desc");

                    if (Integer.valueOf(code) == 1) {

                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");

                        HomeToNew_user_icon = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                        HomeToNew_user_name = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                        HomeToNew_post_time = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                        HomeToNew_post_text = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                        HomeToNew_post_img = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                        HomeToNew_post_likes = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                        HomeToNew_post_pid = new String[jsonArray.length()];
                        HomeToNew_post_comments = new String[jsonArray.length()];

                        NewArrayLength = jsonArray.length();

                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject_item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            HomeToNew_user_icon[i] = jsonObject_item.getString("head");
                            HomeToNew_user_name[i] = jsonObject_item.getString("name");
                            HomeToNew_post_time[i] = jsonObject_item.getString("created");
                            HomeToNew_post_text[i] = jsonObject_item.getString("txt");
                            HomeToNew_post_img[i] = jsonObject_item.getString("img");
                            HomeToNew_post_likes[i] = jsonObject_item.getString("gd");
                            HomeToNew_post_comments[i] = jsonObject_item.getString("co");
                            HomeToNew_post_pid[i] = jsonObject_item.getString("pid");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "NewPost API code: " + code + ", desc: " + desc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "NewPost data null!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `NewFragment`:

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment {

    public static String TAG = "NewFragment";

    private RecyclerView postcardRecycler;
    private ArrayList<PostCard> post_data = new ArrayList<>();
    private PostCardImageAdapter adapter;

    private String[] user_icon, user_name, post_time, post_text, post_img, post_likes, post_comments, post_pid = null;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_layout, container, false);
        user_icon = HomePageActivity.HomeToNew_user_icon;
        user_name = HomePageActivity.HomeToNew_user_name;
        post_time = HomePageActivity.HomeToNew_post_time;
        post_text = HomePageActivity.HomeToNew_post_text;
        post_img = HomePageActivity.HomeToNew_post_img;
        post_likes = HomePageActivity.HomeToNew_post_likes;
        post_comments = HomePageActivity.HomeToNew_post_comments;
        post_pid = HomePageActivity.HomeToNew_post_pid;

        postcardRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.new_layout_recycler);

        for(int i = 0; i < HomePageActivity.NewArrayLength; i++){
            post_data.add(new PostCard(user_icon[i], user_name[i], post_time[i], post_text[i], post_img[i], post_likes[i], post_comments[i], post_pid[i]));
        }

        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        postcardRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new PostCardImageAdapter(getActivity(), post_data);
        postcardRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.new_layout_swipe_refresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                Log.e(TAG, "Enter New onRefresh!");
                HomePageActivity.refresh_New_Data();
                NewFragment fragment = new NewFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Here is my `new_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/new_layout_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/new_layout_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

method **FragmentTransaction#replace** require a **containerViewId** but not `layoutId`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace_1
so that, when you call **replace(R.layout.new_layout, fragment)** will throw an exception

Solution: You can store newFragment in HomePageActivity and add method inflateData in NewFragment. When fetch data success, will call newFragment.inflateData()

Comment: In HomePageActivity, I have a viewPager to load Fragment, so I change getFragmentManager() to replace the viewPager, it will not crash but the app show nothing,

Comment: Do you try keep an instance of NewFragment (ex: newFragment) and add method NewFragment#inflateData. At onPostExecute, call newFragment.inflateData()